# extracting postal addresses from pdf files

Tags: regex, pdf, text, data-mining, text-mining

Are there any libraries/toolkits that would help me in the task of extracting postal address information from unstructured PDF documents (e.g. letters)? If not, how would you approach this task?

I thought about using an open source PDF library and searching for the information with regex patterns, but I'm not sure if it's possible to reliably identify addresses with this simple approach. Unfortunately, the data mining course I attended didn't touch text mining, but only dealt with highly structured data. Maybe someone working on natural language processing knows a useful library or toolkit?

Comment: Why, because I have a generic user name?

Comment: No, because you're asking how to parse unstructured PDF documents and strip out postal address data without a reasonable explanation. Defensive replies such as yours only backup my suspicions.

Comment: Oh, you mean an explanation why I want to do it. Yeah, I guess without it, my intentions could be classified as malicious. Well it is for a (possible) project for a national postal service. They have loads of PDF letter documents, and they want to extract address information for some kind of serial letter campaign. So i guess it IS spam, but official spam.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend http://pdfbox.apache.org for reading pdf(i.e converting to text) and http://code.google.com/p/graph-expression/ for writting Post address grammar.

Comment: Thank you very much, GExp even has an example dealing with address extraction: http://code.google.com/p/graph-expression/wiki/USAAddressExtraction

Answer (score 0):

Use pdf2xml or any other PDF library/toolkit and use your favorite search engine to search for "postal address extraction" and restrict your search to the filetype pdf.

Comment: That's not the point. The point is how to identify address information in unstructured text like a letter. The pdf documents are provided by the customer.

Comment: Ignore the part about pdf. Did you try to do the recommended web search?

Comment: If you are referring to this thesis: http://www.cs.dal.ca/~zyu/research/Thesis.pdf , then thanks. I've already seen it before posting the question, and it is quite interesting indeed.